# How to automatically filter out the best fitting after perform different fittings to data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, data-fitting

The problem is as above. I have two columns of data, x and y, from which I can draw a scatterplot. Now what I would like to do is to fit with linear and polynomial (order: 2), respectively. So, is there a way, such as a formula, to compare the R<sup>2</sup> value and then export the comparsion result somewhere in the same sheet? Thanks!

[image]

For example, if the linear model fits better, export '1' as the value in A1, otherwise export '2'.